# Error converting date to datetime

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, datetime

Im selecting a date in my input date with jQuery datepicker.

The format that Im using in datepicker script is: `dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',`

So I get this date in my input: "Quinta-feira, 1 Maio, 2014" (portuguese date).

But now I need to convert this date to save like datetime in mysql.

I needed only to use this code below if the date was in english:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $_POST['date']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

But my date isnt english so I need to do the conversion and Im trying to use the function below" convertDate" to do this.

But when I call the function, and I pass the input date value like this:   `convertDate($_POST['date']);`

I got an **error** "*Call to a member function format() on a non-object* in this line: `$day= $date->format("l");`

Do you see something wrong here? Because the fucntion seems good for me!

```
function convertDate($myDate){

        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $myDate);
        $day    = $date->format("l");
        $daynum = $date->format("j");
        $month  = $date->format("F");
        $year   = $date->format("Y");

        switch($day)
        {
            case "Segunda-Feira":    $day = "Monday";  break;
            case "Terça-Feira":      $day = "Tuesday"; break;
            case "Quarta-Feira":     $day = "Wednesday";  break;
            case "Quinta-Feira":     $day = "Thursday"; break;
            case "Sexta-Feira":      $day = "Friday";  break;
            case "Sábado":           $day = "Saturday";  break;
            case "Domingo":          $day = "Sunday";  break;
            default:                 $day = "Unknown"; break;
        }

        switch($month)
        {
            case "Janeiro":    $month = "January";    break;
            case "Fevereiro":  $month = "February";   break;
            case "Março":      $month = "March";     break;
            case "Abril":      $month = "April";     break;
            case "Maio":       $month = "May";       break;
            case "Junho":      $month = "June";      break;
            case "Julho":      $month = "July";      break;
            case "Agosto":     $month = "August";    break;
            case "Setembro":   $month = "September"; break;
            case "Outubro":    $month = "October";   break;
            case "Novembro":   $month = "November";  break;
            case "Dezembro":   $month = "December";  break;
            default:           $month = "Unknown";   break;
        }

    echo $daynum . ", " . $month . ", " . $year;
}
```

Trying with str_ireplace:

```
$english = array("Segunda-Feira","Terça-Feira","Quarta-Feira","Quinta-Feira","Sexta-Feira","Sábado","Domingo");
$portuguese = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"); 
$result= str_ireplace ($english , $portuguese, $_POST['date']);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $result);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

I got same error in `echo $date->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: Do a `var_dump($myDate)` and show us the results please.

Comment: I get this: "string(25) "Sexta-feira, 2 Maio, 2014"", that is the date I selected in my datepicker!

Comment: You're right back at the same problem you had in your last question. That date format won't work for `DateTime()` (and your format in createFromFormat is incorrect). I recommend using a regular expression to break this date string up into the parts you need. From there the rest of your code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, in the first line of your function you try to convert your Portuguese date as if it is in the `Ymd` format so your `$date` object is flawed to begin with.

What you should probably do (assuming that there is no localized function to convert Portuguese dates to DateTime...), is use something like a string replace to replace all Portuguese words with English words and after that use your original conversion:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $translated_date);
```

The 17 / 34 words concerned don't interfere with each other so [`str_ireplace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) with two arrays should do it.

Comment: Thanks it seems a good solution, I didnt know this function but it seems like a good solution. But I'm having the same error as my function convertDate().

Comment: @OzzC You forgot to add the months as well. And after the translation you should do a `var_dump($result);` to verify that it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you, I really forget the months! And now I think Im closer, but Im having an error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime coudld not be converted to string in my sql row $insertNews->bindValue(':date', $date);. But I already useDateTime::format to get a formatted string. Do you know why this error can be happening?

Comment: Well, I get it and I solve the problem, doing $newDate = $newDate->format('Y-m-d');. But now my date its not inserting on database, i need to understand why now, but the problem of this question was solved, so thank you very much for your idea!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to translate dates in words in possibly various languages, you can have JQuery drop a UTC of sorts in a hidden form field and work with this instead:

This will return a JS date object:

```
   var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
```

This will make a PHP UTC from it (it's microseconds in JS...)

```
   var phputc = Math.ceil((currentDate.getTime()/1000));
```

This will put in in a hidden form:

```
   $(".selector" ).change(
        function()
        {
             var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
             var phputc = Math.ceil((currentDate.getTime()/1000));
             document.forms[0].nameofhiddenformfield.value = phputc;
        }
   );
```

Make sure there is a field like this in your form

```
   <input type="hidden" name="nameofhiddenformfield" />
```

And on the PHP side you can then do:

```
   $dateUTC = $_POST['nameofhiddenformfield'];
   echo date('Y-m-d',$dateUTC);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but Im strangly Im getting this error:  date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in. When I do  echo date('Y-m-d',$dateUTC);

Comment: The dump of $dateUTC is empty like "string(0) ""

Comment: Difficult to say what goes wrong. The jquery function i posted works fine (tested it), but of course you are supposed to analyze and reproduce , not just cut&paste. Have you created the hidden form field in the form? Is the post variable send to the server alright?